# applying filter state with react

Tags: c#, arrays, reactjs, filter, redux

I have a list of topics which belongs to at least one group, each topic can have 1 group or multiple groups. I am using react fetch to return an object that contains a list of these topics and groups. The page renders a list of groups as list items and the topics just below. I want to be able to filter the list of topics according to what groups has been selected. I have included XML format for part of the data being returned.

I am new to react and have saw different ways of implementing filters but I could not find anything suitable for this in particular. The state of topics should update for each group selected. Groups are selected here:-

Any help would be great, thanks

```
<a className="navigator-tags">
    {item.name}
</a>
```

React code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './PracticeAreas.css';
import IReportGroup from 'src/model/IReportGroup';
import { IReportTopicSummary, IReportTopic } from 'src/model/IReport';

export interface IReportTopicSummary {
    id: string,
    name: string
}

export interface IReportTopic {
    id: string
    name: string
}


interface IOwnProps {
    type: 0
}

interface IOwnState {
    groups: IReportGroup[],
    topics: IReportTopic[],
}

class PracticeAreas extends React.Component<IOwnProps, IOwnState> {

    constructor(props: IOwnProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          groups: [],
          topics: []
        }
        this.data();
      }

    public render() {

        const { topics } = this.state;

        return topics ?
            this.renderData(topics) :
            this.renderLoading();
    }

    public renderLoading () {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    public renderData(data: any) {
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
            return (
            <div className="col-md-12 practiceAreas">
                <h1>Practice Areas</h1>
                <div className="item-container plain-bg selection-refinement">
                    <div className="refinement-search">
                        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <ul className="list-inline groupedTags">
                    {this.state.groups.map((item,i) => 
                        <li key={i}>
                            <a className="navigator-tags">
                                {item.name}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    )}
                </ul>

                <div className="row practiceAreasContainer">
                    {this.state.topics.map((item,i) => 
                        <div key={i} className="result">
                            <div className="col-md-6 result-item">
                                <div className="item-container default shadowed item-content highlight row">
                                    <div className="col-sm-12 no-padding">
                                        <p>Editor: <a href="#">John Sinclair</a>, <a href="#">Eric Draven</a>, <a href="#">Coco Zames</a></p>
                                        <p><a href="#">Beiten Burkhardt</a></p>
                                        <div className="row no-margin">
                                            <div className="col-12 col-sm-10 text-content">
                                                <h3>
                                                    <a href="#">{item.name}</a>
                                                </h3>
                                                <p className="summary">

                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-10 col-sm-2 links-container rhs">
                                                <a href="#">Compare</a>
                                                <div className="divider" />
                                                <a href="#">View</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className="row text-center">
                    <a className="lex-primary-btn medium-btn">Load more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            );
        } else {
            return <div>No items found</div>;
        }
    }

    public data() {
        fetch(`...api/v2/navigator/reports/groups`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }})
        .then((res) => res.json()
        .then((data) => { 
            this.setState({ 
                groups: data.groups,
                topics: data.data
            });
        }));
    }
}

export default PracticeAreas
```

Data example

```
<ReportSelectionCriteriaResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    <Data xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
        <d2p1:NavigatorReportSelection>
            <d2p1:About>test title 4</d2p1:About>
            <d2p1:Groups xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                <d4p1:guid>d21384b5-27be-4bfc-963d-0d2ad40dbbfb</d4p1:guid>
            </d2p1:Groups>
            <d2p1:Id>2fb2783c-f48e-4d49-8098-0d39e4a16e7a</d2p1:Id>
            <d2p1:Name>Test</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:ParentId i:nil="true"/>
            <d2p1:Selected>false</d2p1:Selected>
            <d2p1:Type>Topics</d2p1:Type>
            <d2p1:Visible>true</d2p1:Visible>
        </d2p1:NavigatorReportSelection>
        <d2p1:NavigatorReportSelection>
            <d2p1:About i:nil="true"/>
            <d2p1:Groups xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                <d4p1:guid>2fb2783c-f48e-4d49-8098-0d39e4a16e7a</d4p1:guid>
            </d2p1:Groups>
            <d2p1:Id>47cb7f1d-2267-426c-9f7f-0df3b9291fb7</d2p1:Id>
            <d2p1:Name>Another test topic</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:ParentId i:nil="true"/>
            <d2p1:Selected>false</d2p1:Selected>
            <d2p1:Type>Topics</d2p1:Type>
            <d2p1:Visible>true</d2p1:Visible>
        </d2p1:NavigatorReportSelection>
    </Data> 
    <Groups xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
        <d2p1:NavigatorReportSelectionGroup>
            <d2p1:Focused>false</d2p1:Focused>
            <d2p1:Id>2fb2783c-f48e-4d49-8098-0d39e4a16e7a</d2p1:Id>
            <d2p1:Name>Allan's Test group</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Order>0</d2p1:Order>
            <d2p1:Type>Topics</d2p1:Type>
        </d2p1:NavigatorReportSelectionGroup>
        <d2p1:NavigatorReportSelectionGroup>
            <d2p1:Focused>false</d2p1:Focused>
            <d2p1:Id>47cb7f1d-2267-426c-9f7f-0df3b9291fb7</d2p1:Id>
            <d2p1:Name>Another test topic group</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Order>1</d2p1:Order>
            <d2p1:Type>Topics</d2p1:Type>
        </d2p1:NavigatorReportSelectionGroup>
    </Groups>
</ReportSelectionCriteriaResponse>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement a filter is to simply store what the currently selected group is in state:

```
this.state = {
   groups: [],
   topics: [],
   selectedGroup: ''
}
```

or if the selected group is specified in another manner (route, etc) it could be a prop.

Once you are aware of what the selected group is, inside your iteration of topics you can apply the filter in realtime and only display topics that pass the filter. For example:

```
this.state.topics.filter(topic => this.isTopicInCurrentGroup(topic)).map((item,i) => {
 // return your existing <div >( display for item)</div
})
```

You would then implement what ever logic you needed to determine if the topic is in the current group and return true or false. For example:

```
isTopicInCurrentGroup = (topic) => { 
  return (topic.groupId === this.state.selectedGroup || !this.state.selectedGroup);
}
```

Comment: thank you, would you also be able to show me how groups are selected and is in the state?